# Qt c++ Wrap text (richtext) in tableview

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, word-wrap

I use QItemDelegate and QStandardItemModel to display text and images in a QTableView (text and images are stored as richText in my database).

The problem is, that the text does not wrap, when i use QItemDelegate. 
If i do not use QItemDelegate the text does wrap but images are not displayed.

My Question: How can i make text-wrapping when using ItemDelegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with `Qt::TextWrapAnywhere` flag in `DrawText` method.

```
painter->drawText(xText, yText, wText, hText, 
                  Qt::TextWrapAnywhere | Qt::AlignCenter, QString("  ")
             .append(m_RowsWithIconAndText.value(index.row())));
```